# Problems with activity lifecycle

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have some problems with starting new activity. In my app I have setup broadcast receiver which listens for intent (screen off). When screen is off, my app should start new activity (under certain conditions of course. I'm not making spam app). But sometimes it isn't.

I have declared that activity "singleTop" in my manifest, so I override "onNewIntent" method also.(I think it's important to tell this) But here is the thing.

When phone goes to sleep and if certain conditions are met, then 2 icons appear on the screen (My activity). I made those icons clickable, and if I click my second icon I'm FINISHING (finish()) current activity and I'm starting new CALL LOG activity (owned by Android). When I do that, it should bring back previous activity (with different layout - only one icon - previous displayed together with second one), but again only if phone goes to sleep. The thing is that it doesn't. According to my LOGCAT, all conditions are met but only activity is not started. What is happening with my activity lifecyle here?

Screen Off Receiver code:

```
@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("APP", "MAINSERVICE, Screen OFF");


            MissedCallObserver mco = new MissedCallObserver(MainService.this);

        if(!CallListener.isCallActive) {
            Log.d("APP", "MAINSERVICE, INSIDE IF ( call is not active )");

            if(mco.checkMissedCalls() > 0 || mco.checkUnreadSms() > 0) {
                Log.d("APP", "MAINSERVICE, calls calculated. IF entered. Next is starting activity");

            startHandleActivity();
            }
        }
    } // outer if


    } // ScreenOffReceiver




private void startHandleActivity() {


        Intent startH_Activity = new Intent(MainService.this, HandleActivity.class);
        startH_Activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startH_Activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(startH_Activity);


    }
```

Comment: post the code in your receiver for the screen off event, you might also need to request a partial wakelock since when the screen goes off your device maybe going to sleep as well.

Comment: i did, please look at it now :)

Comment: Does your app grab a partial wakelock? I could foresee that if you are waiting for the screen off broadcast, the processor could potentially sleep right after, and hence the Activity won't get created.

Comment: "Does your app grab a partial wakelock?"  No..

So you think i should use that? Strange thing is that its working on some devices, and on some it dont ( real devices. tested on 4. )

Comment: Absolutely you need a partial wakelock, that is my guess as to why it works some times and not other, the device is going to sleep some times soon after.

Comment: ok thanks. But just another thing. According to android docs

"If you hold a partial wake lock, the CPU will continue to run, regardless of any display timeouts or the state of the screen and even after the user presses the power button. In all other wake locks, the CPU will run, but the user can still put the device to sleep using the power button."

When "home" screen is visible and i press power button ( and again depends on conditions ), my activity is always showed. So device goes to sleep according to docs, but my activity is still showed.

Comment: @rootpanthera, yeah I agree with draksia. It appears to me that there is a race condition between when you receive the screen off broadcast and when/if the processor goes to sleep.

Comment: aaaah. Ok you guys just cleared my mind. Thank you both for helping me.

And i always thought that device ALWAYS goes to sleep when screen is turned OFF, but it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
wl.acquire();
```

This will allow to execute code reliably after the Screen Off Intent fires.